# Append elements dynamically to another dynamic element

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, append

I want to append the variable `img` to a `figure` element. Everything is loaded dynamically from a JSON file. And everything seems to work just fine except when I have to append the element to the existing `$wrap`

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var url = arr[i].url,
      img = $('<img src="'+ url +'">').load(function(){
          var imgW = this.width,
              imgH = this.height;

          img.attr({
              width: imgW,
              height: imgH
          });
      });

  $wrap.append( '<figure>' + img + '</figure>' );
}
```

When I perform `$wrap.append( img );` everything works as I expected. The element are appended to `$wrap`. The **problem** is that I don't have to append them to `$wrap` but each of them (according to the array length) must be appended to its proper `<figure>` tag so when I perform this code: `$wrap.append( '<figure>' + img + '</figure>' );` which is the one I want, the output is: `<figure>[object Object]</figure>`.

Any advise?
How to append a dynamically created element to an other dynamically created element?

you can find the code [here](https://github.com/dcdeiv/jsonslider/blob/development/jquery.jsonslider.js)

and [here](https://github.com/dcdeiv/jsonslider/tree/development)

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
$wrap.append($('<figure/>').append(img));
```

`'<figure>' + img + '</figure>'` is `string + Object + string`. Js will return the result as a string, which means it'll call `.toString()` function to convert every variable that isn't a string to a string. `img` is a jQuery object and not a string , so `img.toString()` will be called and the result of that is `[object Object]`

Comment: This works but attributes don't show up. I need that the img tags come with the height and width attributes I added before.

Comment: @user2153436 this works! Your code works perfectly thanks. Can I ask you why attributes show up only in the last img tag?